How to specify a directory for bazel test XML output?
In my current project we use Bazel as a building tool. We have created a CI pipeline which runs a bunch of bazel test commands to execute unit tests of the code. In the current implementation, after a test is run, we have to move the resulting JUnit-style XML file from the directory where Bazel generated it to a different location. We would like to be able to skip this step and be able to force Bazel to generate the file directly in the directory we choose.
From my understanding, the environmental variable XML_OUTPUT_FILE is created by Bazel at runtime and used to store a path to the XML file that will be generated. I tried setting it to my target directory by using --test_env, but failed, since Bazel overwritten it anyway.
